# How to draw text in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawing, uitextview

How to draw text in UITextView just like there is a method called "drawTextInRect:" in UILabel and UITextField. Should I implement it in "drawRect:" or "drawLayer:inContext:". Thank your focus and patient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use drawinrect like following code.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:kCellFontSize];

/// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
/// Set line break mode
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
/// Set text alignment
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };

[text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
```